# Move duplicated routes code in emberjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have two very similar routes:

```js
App.DiscountRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            categories: this.store.findAll('discountCategory'),
            discounts: this.store.findAll('discount'),
            total_size: 6
        });
    }
});
```

and

```js
App.CategoryRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render('discount');
    },
    model: function(params) {
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            categories: this.store.findAll('discountCategory'),
            discounts: this.store.filter('discount',function(discount) {
                return discount.get('discountCategory').get('id')==params.category_id
            }),
            total_size: 6
        });
    }
});
```

Where should I place categories model and total_size counter, which will be  available from any routes  in my application?

Comment: Application route is a decent place for storing application wide state info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Kingpin2k pointed out in the comments, `Application` route is probably your best bet for storing application-wide state info, since `Application` route will always fire before the other routes. I believe this can be done in 1 of 2 ways.

1. You can invoke the `application` model in other routes using `modelFor('application')`
2. You can use the `needs` API as described [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/dependency-injection-and-service-lookup/#toc_lightweight-services-with-code-needs-code)